# How to retrieve app usage statistics of an android device?

Tags: android, usage-statistics, android-activitymanager

I'm constantly trying new apps and my phone is getting cluttered with old apps, I no longer use. So, I thought I'd develop a simple app to help me out. There are similar apps, but none does exactly what I want:

I would like to have a list of apps which I've installed in the last month, which I've used X number of times (for easy access: They may be keepers!) as well as those I've not used in Y weeks.

Is there any way to get app usage statistics with Android? I guess ActivityManager might help me to gather that statistics, but is there a way to read just when an app has been used last? Or how many times in a given period?

Any tips will be most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out my app for uninstallation of the apps you don't need : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager .

Also, if you wish to find exact usage statistics of your apps, you can use my app this way: find "settings" (the app itself) inside the list (you can perform a search query), choose to make a shortcut of it, and then choose on the dialog "Usage Statistics". This way you can perform both the operations you wanted.

I also plan on adding this feature somehow in the future, but that's what you can do for now.

Here's a screenshot (it's the first on what I show here) :

[image]